# Layout issue in high resolution device android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to make below listview row file
[image]

So I have set layout row file code as below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_left"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="70">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/ckh"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5dp" />

                    <customtext.BoldText
                        android:id="@+id/task_title"
                        style="@style/NormalTextView"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_2dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ckh"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:text="Title"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_11" />

                    <customtext.RegularText
                        android:id="@+id/task_assign"
                        style="@style/NormalTextView"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/task_title"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/task_title"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_2dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ckh"
                        android:background="@drawable/rect_full"
                        android:padding="@dimen/margin_2dp"
                        android:text="Title"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_8" />

                    <customtext.RegularText
                        android:id="@+id/task_date"
                        style="@style/NormalTextView"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/task_assign"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/task_assign"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_5dp"
                        android:text="Title"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_2dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_10" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_right"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="30"
                android:background="@drawable/rect_task_edit_delete"
                android:gravity="center|right">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_edit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/edit" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_delete"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/delete" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run this in normal device like 480x800 than it will give output like below image
[image]

And when I run this in high resolution device like 1080x1920 with (320dpi)(Sony xperia z Ultra) at that time i give below output
[image]

So any idea how can I maintain this layout in very high resolution devices?

Comment: use weight sum in ll_right childs

Comment: You have set background color to main right layout therefore this will happen in different devices, so better is clear background color of main right layout and then add one sub layout in in it with wrap content width and give background to it

Comment: @Vickyexpert: can you post your answer so i can get better idea?

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya check below my anser

Comment: In your both `ImageView` just add this property `android:layout_weight="1"` it will take Both Image to divided equal width.

Comment: are you putting the drawable for higher densities. For example if the delete icon is 50x50 in hdpi, you need to put it in xxhpdi as 100x100,

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your code with images and variables in one of my projects. I recommend you to change the LinearLayout with the weight sum of 100 to a relative layout and put the item you want to fix the size to align parent right. Here is an example which work. You can fix the relativelayout root height. Hope it help

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_items"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1.5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_connexion"
            android:gravity="center|right">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_edit"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/statut_presence_jaune" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_delete"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/statut_presence_vert" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/ckh"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/task_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ckh"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="Title"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/task_assign"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/task_title"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/task_title"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ckh"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:text="Title"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/task_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/task_assign"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/task_assign"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="Title"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

change weight for your view with id

```
android:id="@+id/ll_left"
```

to 1. And delete your view with id

```
android:id="@+id/ll_right"
```

and replace it with following line of code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_img_edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_task_edit_delete"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/edit" />

    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_img_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_task_edit_delete"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_delete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/delete" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

in this you can change margin value as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

instead of this

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_right"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_task_edit_delete"
            android:gravity="center|right">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_edit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/edit" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_delete"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/delete" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

use this for the image Linear layout your problem will be solved...

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_right"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="30"
                android:background="@drawable/rect_task_edit_delete"
                android:gravity="center|right">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_edit"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/edit" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_delete"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/delete" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

**Note:-This issue due to you make it imageView wrap-content and Linear Layout with weight so Linear layout adjust due to its weight But imageView is wrap content.So it vary device to device .....**

Answer (score 1):

In your LinearLayout which contains Imageviews delete and edit.You have specified right margin to them remove that and weight sum here.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your second layout by below,

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_right"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center|right">

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="@drawable/rect_task_edit_delete"
               android:gravity="center|right">

               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/img_edit"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_20dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/edit" />

               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/img_delete"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/delete" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `weightSum` property with second Layout.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_right"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
            android:weighSum = "1"
            android:layout_marginRight="1.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_task_edit_delete"
            android:gravity="center|right">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_edit"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/edit" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_delete"
               android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/delete" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add both `ImageView` weight property like below way. So it will take equal width to both `ImageView`.

```
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_edit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/edit"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_delete"    
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/delete"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>
```